# Drag down a cell and get the values that increment by columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

As shown in the image below, what I need is to drag down the cell and get the values as shown in the yellow cells.  The values will go into successive rows, but will be taken from every 4th column, from the same row as the value I drag down.

In this example, the cell I'm dragging references B1, so the cell below it should reference F1, the next cell J1, etc.

[image]

I've tried Googling a solution, and tried using OFFSET and INDIRECT functions without success.

Comment: So are you trying to add values or increment them? I think a more detailed explanation would be helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't detailed enough, what I wanted to do is what Scott Craner answered, thank you very much anyways!

Comment: Glad you got a solution! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use Index:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)+ 2)
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH Scott Craner! That was just what I wanted to do! :D
Could you explain me how does it work?

Comment: As it is copied down Row(1:1) which returns 1 changes to Row(2:2) which is 2 and so forth. So the second par tof the index returns the index number.  So Row(1:1) returns 2.  So it returns the second cell in row 1.  When it is draged/copied down the math resolves to 6 and so forth.